# Which Akame ga KILL! manga should I read if I want to continue the storyline of the anime?

Tags: akame-ga-kill

I saw there are various manga with *Akame ga KILL!* in their names.

The ones I have found are:

- [Akame ga KILL!](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=52028)
- [Akame ga KILL! Zero](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=102282)

Which one should I read if I want to continue the storyline of the anime?

Comment: There are only 2 series, confirmed from [Wikipedia Japanese](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AB%E3%83%A1%E3%81%8C%E6%96%AC%E3%82%8B!#.E5.8D.98.E8.A1.8C.E6.9C.AC)

Comment: @nhahtdh So who the third one belongs to?

Comment: I'm quite sure it is an alternate name for the Zero series. (Note that the Japanese name is Akame ga Kiru, but its Engrish title underneath is Akame ga KILL).

Comment: Hinowa ga yuku. It deals with akame going to another land after the events of the manga.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Akame ga KILL! Zero is a sort of prequel which tells the story of Akame when she was a part of the government's army, how she was trained and so on. The anime is following the Akame ga KILL! (non zero) manga and from what I can recall is close to chapter 48 of the manga as of episode 18.

So, if you want to follow the story of the anime read the first title you posted, the Zero version is a prequel which introduces some characters which may or may not be met again in the principal storyline.

Answer (score 9):

[*Akame ga KILL!*](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=52028) is the main series, while [*Akame ga KILL! Zero*](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=102282) is a complementary series which tells the story of the characters before timeline of the main series.

You should read *Akame ga KILL!* if you want to continue from the anime.

---

The story is generally the same up to episode 17/chapter 33. However, the anime begins to have minor deviations from the manga from episode 18/chapter 34. After chapter 38, which corresponds to episode 19, the anime totally skips more than 10 chapters starting from chapter 39, except for this plot point in chapter 43, where

> Susanoo died fighting Esdeath to let the rest of the Night Raid escape. Originally, this happened during the mission to assassinate Borick, which spans from chapter 40 to chapter 43. In the anime, Susanoo's death is moved to episode 21 instead, and Borick's assassination is trivialized at the end of episode 19.

Episode 20 restarts from second half of chapter 50, but doesn't follow the manga too closely, since the manga introduces many new characters during the Wild Hunt arc (from chapter 44 to 48), and several of them affect the story beyond Wild Hunt arc.

Most of the differences between manga and anime adaptation come from this 10-chapter gap.

If you have time, I suggest that you scan through the manga from the beginning, so that you won't miss any details that might have been omitted from the anime adaptation. Otherwise, **chapter 39 is a good place to pick up the manga**.

Comment: That is nice to know so I gave you +1, but the first answer was more precise.