# Why is the anime of Akame ga Kill so different from the manga?

Tags: anime-production, akame-ga-kill

I haven't read the manga of Akame ga Kill, but I have read that it is really different from the anime.  They even skipped 10 chapter of the manga completely.  Why did they decide to do that?  Was it because the show has to be done in a short amount of episodes or something else?

Comment: I think you and the answerer are confused. The answerer read your question as "why chapter 10 is skipped", while your question is about why [10 chapters are skipped from chapter 39](http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/15129/1398). And you seem to be confused by the answer and accepted it.

Comment: I don't think he's only referring to that! Like, Mine dies in the anime and tatsumi didn't unlock his cool new form! Those are radical differences and I too would like to know why they didn't adapt the manga somewhat closer to what really happen.

Comment: Even after 10449 views, still no answer :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I come with an answer from Polymanga 2015 in Switzerland when the author was there. You can verify it here: [Polymanga 2015](http://www.polymanga.com/?lang=fr)

The following question was asked and the author answered:

> At the beginning of the anime, the manga was already written but in the end the anime exceeded the manga. That's the reason why I want to change the story because the people who had already seen the anime know the end and they will find the manga boring.

It's not his words exactly (I don't remember exactly) but it's the general idea of what he wanted to say.

And after that, he adds:

> The end of the anime was fantastic. But the end of the manga will be more fantastic.

For the ones who didn't see the end, let's go see it;)

Comment: It seems that there is no transcript for the interview?

Comment: @nhahtdh I am looking for. But I don't know. I contacted the organizer. Now, we need to wait.

Comment: @nhahtdh sorry, i had no answer from the organizer and I can't find a transcript

Comment: I can vouch for this answer, as I was present at polymanga ´15 during the questioning.