# What are the differences between the Akame Ga Kill! manga and anime?

Tags: akame-ga-kill

First of all, why was the anime completed before the manga? As far as I am aware, the anime is ahead of the latest manga chapters by a large margin.

I've heard that the anime actually differs from the manga; does this mean we might get a remake like *Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood* for *Fullmetal Alchemist*?

Furthermore, will the manga continue on with Akame's story? Will it explain some of the plot holes that were left unanswered in the anime?

Comment: Related: https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/15136/why-is-the-anime-of-akame-ga-kill-so-different-from-the-manga, https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/15124/what-akame-ga-kill-manga-should-i-read-if-i-want-to-continue-the-story-line-of

Comment: something tells me there is penitential for more simply because the mention of a weapon that could bring people back to live in the early episodes seems to me to be complete odd and out of character for the rest of the anmie so maybe there is one like that out there? we never sure all 48 and there were ones that were not in the book about them. lets hope XD

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How different are the anime and manga versions of Akame Ga Kill?](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/19837/how-different-are-the-anime-and-manga-versions-of-akame-ga-kill)

Answer (score 8):

### Difference between the anime and manga of *Akame ga KILL!*

I have listed out some of the differences between the anime and manga of *Akame ga KILL!* [in this answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/15124/what-akame-ga-kill-manga-should-i-read-if-i-want-to-continue-the-story-line-of/15129#15129). Let me reproduce it here for posterity.

> The story is generally the same up to episode 17/chapter 33. However, the anime begins to have minor deviations from the manga from episode 18/chapter 34. After chapter 38, which corresponds to episode 19, the anime totally skips more than 10 chapters starting from chapter 39, except for this plot point in chapter 43, where
>
> > ... Susanoo died fighting Esdeath to let the rest of the Night Raid escape. Originally, this happened during the mission to assassinate Borick, which spans from chapter 40 to chapter 43. In the anime, Susanoo's death is moved to episode 21 during the rescue for Tatsumi instead, and Borick's assassination is trivialized at the end of episode 19.
>
> Episode 20 restarts from second half of chapter 50, but doesn't follow the manga too closely, since the manga introduces many new characters during the Wild Hunt arc (from chapter 44 to 48), and several of them affect the story beyond Wild Hunt arc.
>
> Most of the differences between manga and anime adaptation come from this 10-chapter gap.

### Possibility of a remake ending

It's not unprecedented and even common for the anime to have an original ending, when the anime runs out of source material. Heck, for the case of *Fullmetal Alchemist*, the 2003 anime branched off from the manga half-way and followed its own original storyline.

For the case of *Akame ga KILL!*, it is extremely unlikely that it gets a remake. Unlike the case of *Fullmetal Alchemist (2003)* anime where the plot in the manga was still developing, *Akame ga KILL!* manga is currently on its way to the ending. The anime's ending also prohibits any logical extension to the story, and an anime continuation would require a completely new arc in the manga, plus great demand from fans.

Since the manga is currently on-going, only time will tell whether the manga has the same ending as the anime or not, or whether there is any extension to the story of the characters who survives.

Comment: FMA managed to get that far ahead of the manga even after using adventure towns?

Answer (score 1):

There are also several exclusions of the story of several side characters. 
For example the anime completely leaves out the Wild Hunt without which viewers never find out Run's story (it's touched on in the anime but never developed).
Because the anime ended early, people will never know the story of people like Wave.

Spoiler:

> Lubbock gets killed by Budo after escaping being tortured in prison by Syura.

And there will probably never be a remake - it's just too brutal...

But you should definitely read the manga.

Comment: Actually, it's not Budo who killed him, but the samurai dude from Wild Hunt.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same from episode 1 to 18, but after that, they did many shortcuts:

- Borik's assassination became "easy np"
- They skipped the Wild Hunt Arc
- Transformed many awesome combats and just ruined it. Most of them are short silly combats, removing most of the meaning et deap of some characters.

The adaptation was quite disappointing.

Answer (score -1):

And the elite team by Shura is skipped so much even the connection between Ran's past and one of the member. In the end Ran did his revenge but death in the end...

Comment: Please add more explanation on your answer